# Preact render component to specified div

Tags: javascript, preact

Since preact application generated from preact cli does not come with any `index.html`, every component render will append to the body tag, but I want to render the component in to specified div. **For example** inside 
here is my `component/app.js`

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import { Router } from 'preact-router';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import Header from './header';

// Code-splitting is automated for routes
import Home from '../routes/home';
import Profile from '../routes/profile';
import Github from '../routes/github';
import List from '../routes/list';

export default class App extends Component {

    /** Gets fired when the route changes.
     *  @param {Object} event       "change" event from [preact-router](http://git.io/preact-router)
     *  @param {string} event.url   The newly routed URL
     */
    handleRoute = e => {
        this.currentUrl = e.url;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <Header />
                <Router onChange={this.handleRoute}>
                    <Home path="/" />
                    <Profile path="/profile/" user="me" />
                    <Profile path="/profile/:user" />
                    <Github path="/github" />
                    <List path="/list" />
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**and this is my `index.js` in `routes/list`**

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class List extends Component {
  state = {
      data : []
    };
  fetchUser = () => {
      axios.get(`https://api.dev.xxx`)
      .then(response =>{
       const data = response.data.data;
       this.setState({data: data})
      });
  }
  setUsername = e => {
      this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
      this.fetchUser();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchUser();
  }
  render({}, {data}) {
      return (
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Listnya</h1>
          {
              data.map(d=>(
                <div class="card">
                    <p>{d.id}</p>
                    <p>{d.name}</p>
                </div>
              ))
          }
        </div>
      );
   }
}
```

as we can see in the code above that `<div class="container">` will be appended to the body, but I want to render the card inside container div that prespecified. How is this done?

Comment: Which version of preact are you using? Also, are you trying to put it into a div that is not in your current DOM structure?

Comment: The idea in Preact /React is to have whole site in it - in this case you simply import component and use it inside other component. If not, you have to do separate app and just in your app.js / index.js / main.js or however you called it, render your second app in desired div. See docs https://preactjs.com/guide/getting-started#rendering-jsx just do it for your component.

Comment: @pmkro preact cli 2.2.1. Yes, since we dont have any html file to hold the template

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto if the whole page is preact just fill out the rest and put it where you want it. preact-cli assumes that you are generating the whole site with preact

Comment: @pmkro can you provide an example of code?

Comment: Like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko300qzppv). Your question is pretty vague. In general preact will render things to the specified parent. If you want `container` to get rendered into another div, you will need to supply that div. Where are you trying to put it? In what you have provided there is no other div for it to render into

Comment: @pmkro for simplicity, can us create index.html manually? if so, which js should be loaded in index.html

Comment: I don't use `preact-cli` specifically. But could you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish? You say you want `container` to not be placed in the body, but what you have shown us shows no other place for it to go? Where should it go? Again `preact-cli` will build the DOM for you, so don't create a `.html` file. In your render for `List` create a wrapper around `container` in which it should get placed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using release candidate you can upgrade to 3.0:
(which has template.html in root)
https://twitter.com/_prateekbh/status/1114071027238047746